# обработка массива в функции

Tags: c++, массивы, функции

```
 uint32_t algorytm (uint32_t a, uint32_t b, uint32_t c, uint32_t d, uint32_t 
 e, uint32_t f, uint32_t g, uint32_t h, uint32_t k[], uint32_t w[]){
 for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i){
 uint32_t t1 = h + a + e + k[i] + w[i];
 uint32_t t2 = a + b;
 h = g; g = f; f = e; e = d + t1; d = c; c = b; b = a; a = t1 + t2;}  

int main(){
uint32_t n[8] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}; // для примера
uint32_t a = n[0], b = n[1], c = n[2], d = n[3], e = n[4], f = n[5], g = 
n[6], h = n[7]; 

algorytm (a, b,  c,  d,  e,  f,  g,  h, k[], w[]);

uint32_t m[0] = n[0] + a, m[1] =n[1] + b, m[2] =n[2] + c, m[3] =n[3] + d, 
m[4] =n[4] + e, m[5] =n[5] + f, m[6] =n[6] + g, m[7] =n[7] + h;
return 0;
}
```

как все таки верно передать массив в функцию
написано типа так: func(int a, int b, int w[], int i) где i это размер массива, но так не работает почему то.
у меня два массива по 64 элемента, не могу сделать функцию

Comment: так а как вы передаете массив в ф-цию? предоставте код.

Comment: Тут нужен [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), а не *"так не работает почему то"*.

Comment: дописал, да и переменные t1 и t2  я убрал из передаваемых параметров, они временные

Comment: следует использовать другие варианты, vector<> например [![ответ на вопрос от Б. Страуструпа](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRsAw.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRsAw.jpg)

Comment: Что такое "не работает"?

Answer (score 0):

При вызове функции нужно писать не:

```
algorytm (a, b,  c,  d,  e,  f,  g,  h, k[], w[]);
```

а:

```
algorytm (a, b,  c,  d,  e,  f,  g,  h, k, w);
```

так, как вы передаете указаетли на массивы. Тобишь в определении ф-ции: `int m[]` и `int *m` - эквивалентны.

Comment: так тоже не работает, я пробовал и со скобками и без, нужно как-то передавать параметр == номеру элементу массива

Comment: Так вам что собственно нужно: передать в функцию массив или один его элемент?

Comment: мне нужно обработать 8 аргументов a - h, в обработке участвуют массивы k[64] и w[64]

Comment: Стоп, теперь я не понимаю в чем все-таки состоит вопрос? Вы спрашивали как передать массив в ф-цию - я вам ответил (смотрите выше). Что означает "параметр == номеру элемента массива"? Это индекс? В таком случае передавайте в ф-цию индекс. Вообщем определитесь сначала с вопросом, а потом его задавайте

Comment: хорошо, я сформулирую свой вопрос так:
как передать массив как параметр функции в котором в процессе расчета функции используются значения массива поэлементно
например как в этом коде: функция поэлементно складывает значения массива (для 3-го цикла например используется элемент массива w[2]  и k[2]. В обычном цикле если это не функция, все понятно, но как указать это для функции - непонятно.

Comment: Бли! Ну вот какая разница: в функции или в не в функции? Тем более, что main - это тоже функция. Просто передаете в функцию адрес массива и делаете в функции с массивом что захотите. Создается такое ощущение, что вы просто не умеете работать с массивами.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, полегче. Если бы человек умел работать с массивами, он не задавал бы подобные вопросы.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUMBERS_NUM 10 // количество чисел в массиве

int sum(int* array, int numbers_num) {
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers_num; ++i)
        sum += array[i];

    return sum;
}

int main() {
    int array[NUMBERS_NUM] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    // Когда мы пишем sum(array, ...), мы передаем в функцию адрес первого элемента массива (int*).  
    printf("%i\n", sum(array, NUMBERS_NUM));
}
```

Comment: Не адрес массива, а адрес первого элемента массива. Иногда это важно.

Comment: А они разве не совпадают?

Comment: Совпадают, но адрес первого элемента массива имеет тип `int *`, а адрес массива в данном конкретном случае имеет тип `int (*)[10]` и это [не одно и тоже](https://ideone.com/zOhuaw).

Comment: это только для одного массива, а у меня же их 2 в функции

Comment: @ilya, точно также передаете второй - `int sum(int* array1, int* array2, ...)`